# hatching random specific turtles

Tags: netlogo

I an creating a model with 2 breeds, males and females. When the number of turtles becomes less than 100, I want to randomly hatch either breed (both having an equal chance of being created) to return the turtle count to 100. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Care to show us what you've tried?

Comment: '    to reproduce
    ask turtles [ if n-of turtles < 100
    crt turtles = 100
    set breed one-of (list males females)
    ]
   end '       ;; I know this isn't formatted properly, but something along the lines of this

Comment: @Melimel: You can edit your original question to include properly formatted code.